# How to impersonate user but still maintain the admin privileges

Tags: winapi, service

I have a service which runs as a local system.
In the service I need to perform some actions (call `NetworkIsolationSetAppContainerConfig` - trying to solve the isolation exemption issue in Windows 8-10) in the context of all the logged in users.
So I iterate over the users with `WTSEnumerateSessions` and tried 2 approaches:

1. Impersonate - `WTSQueryUserToken` to get the user token, `DuplicateTokenEx` to duplicate it and `SetThreadToken` to use it.
2. Different process - I created a different process which calls `NetworkIsolationSetAppContainerConfig` and in my service I use `WTSQueryUserToken`, `DuplicateTokenEx`, `CreateEnvironmentBlock` and CreateProcessAsUserW to run this process in the context of the users.

Both methods failed with lack of permissions (error number 5 - access denied) on Windows 10.
However when I run my Visual Studio in administrator mode and try to run this function all works fine.
What can I do? How can I run the function in the context of a user but maintain the service admin rights?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see how you can be both the user and localsystem at the same time.

Comment: In this case I can't perform actions for non administrators users that require administrator privileges.. Are you sure?

Comment: Non administrators cannot perform tasks that require administrator rights. That is how the system is designed.

Comment: It is true, but I assumed as local system I could elevate its permissions for some time.

Comment: Localsystem has elevated rights. If you want to perform tasks that require elevated rights, why are you impersonating limited rights users?

Comment: Because I am using a function that I believe should run in a user context because the system account doesn't really have metro apps to use this API. It can only do it for the specific users.

Comment: Impersonation doesn't acquire the entire user context, only the security context.  Using CreateProcessAsUserW gives you the user's full context, but the wrong security context.  Try duplicating your own token and using SetTokenInformation to change the terminal services session to that of the user, then using CreateProcessAsUserW to launch a child process.

Comment: Harry, I will try it. thanks